# How to read a PDF using Powershell

Tags: powershell, pdf, itext7

I am at the beginning of my first real powershell project.  Right now I am trying to read certain fields from a PDF, specifically account number and District ID.  However, despite scouring the internet for a couple of hours, there is not an answer when it comes to using iText 7.  I tried using a iTextSharp video while substituting what I thought was the correct add on for iText 7 but that just failed. I am new to trying to read a PDF and am literally just trying to get it to return the pdf into a text file.  Once I get that, I'll worry about getting the right information.  If there is an easier way to just pull directly from the field, I'm all ears.

**The final task is to pull this information from literally hundreds of the same document.  I'm just trying to get through this process using baby steps.  The fields are typed in, so reading, in theory, should be easy enough

```
Add-Type -Path "file path\itext.pdfa.dll"
$path= "file path\doc.pdf"

$pdf = New-Object iText.text.pdf.PdfReader -ArgumentList $path

$export=""

foreach($page in 1..($pdf.NumberOfPages)){
    $export= 
    [iText.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor]::GetTextFromPage($pdf,$page)
}

$export | Out-File "file path\Test.txt"
```